# XML Sitemap on Demandware / Salesforce CMS for SEO ecommerce maintenance

Tags: xml, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, demandware

I am providing a SEO consultation for a company which uses Demandware as e-commerce solution. They got about 20k (20.000) broken links and I have to fix them with a massive implementation of 301 redirects.

How can I implement my customized sitemap.xml file in Demandware? I can't find any reference and the company's developers seems to know nothing about it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

in SFCC the sitemap generation is done through a job. Go to Merchant Tools > Site Maps.

This job picks the sitemap attributes that were given at category level, product level and finally generates this XML. So you need to know what links are broken. Identify the source of these URLs, fix them. Sitemap job will pick them generate a right XML.